# Unable to create Petalinux BSP in Xilinx SDK

Tags: zynq, bsp, xilinx-edk, petalinux

I am trying to build Petalinux BSP in Xilinx SDK by following the steps given in UG978 document, but i am getting following error.

ERROR:EDK - petalinux () - can't read "env(PETALINUX)": no such variable

make: *** [ps7_cortexa9_0/lib/libxil.a] Error 2

ERROR:EDK - Error(s) while running DRCs.

make: Target `all' not remade because of errors.

What may be the reason for these errors??
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Did you source the settings.sh script from the directory of your petalinux installation?

```
$ source <path-to-installed-PetaLinux>/settings.sh
```

As mentioned in Xilinx petalinux tools documentation:
http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/petalinux2015_2/ug1144-petalinux-tools-reference-guide.pdf

Also check if the PETALINUX environment variable is set correctly to your installation path:

```
echo $PETALINUX
```

Comment: Hi Andreas Gschossmann,

The path was set properly. Now it works fine. Thank you.